# AND statement inside CASE postgreSQL referring to similar condiitons

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use an AND statement inside a CASE statement, referring to the same thing twice:

```
CASE 
WHEN col1 like A then col_A-(col_B/col_C)
WHEN col1 like A AND sum(col2)=0 then col_D 
end as casecolumn
```

However I am finding that only the first WHEN statement is affecting the column, i.e only calculation1 is implemented, how can I make sure both calculations are applied to casecolumn?

Comment: Do it in the other order, first like AND sum, then only like.

Comment: `AND` (boolean) operator, `CASE` expression.

Comment: What are those two calculations?

Comment: This is SQL, not C. The first true WHEN decides which THEN to execute - and nothing else.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of the conditions:

```
CASE WHEN col1 like A AND SUM(col2) = 0 THEN calcuation2
     WHEN coc1 like A THEN calculation1
END AS casecolumn
```

If the `LIKE` and `SUM` criteria be met first, that condition would fire.  Otherwise, the `CASE` expression will flow down to the more lenient criteria for another chance to match.

If you want the "calculation" of both conditions to be applied should both the `LIKE` and `SUM` conditions be true, then just use it when determining the value for that condition.

Comment: OP wants both calculation 1 and calculation 2 in first THEN. Like in C when no `break`.

Comment: @Time Biegeleisen this produced the same behaviour as I was seeing before, only calculation1 was implemented.

Comment: @jarlh Your comment makes no sense.  A `CASE` expression can only output a single value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I know that... But OP doesn't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question to have the actual calculations.

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer doesn't changed based on this.  You have two seemingly unrelated formulas after the two `THEN` in the expression.  What do you want to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the THEN with two conditions  evaluates to true implement the calculation associated, otherwise if the THEN with one condition evaluates to true then implement that calculation.

Comment: @user124123 `SUM(col2) = 0` is very suspicious for me. Note that it can only happen, when f.ex. you have two rows with `-2` and `2` in `col2`. If you have no rows or `NULL`s in `col2`, you'll need to use `COALESCE(SUM(col2), 0) = 0`